# LAMP + Node.js via nginx

Tags: php, apache, node.js, nginx, proxy

I have existing home server with Linux (Debian) + Apache + PHP + MySQL.
I want to add node.js also as an additional dev platform.
Also I read about problem of node.js with static content I saw advices about nginx as a front-end server for node.js.

So currently I want to keep existing parts and extend server with node. Also I want to keep existing apache configuration (hosts, etc).

Please advice how to build such a system an what configuration must be done.

My first version of this is:

nginx on top of Debian server, then nginx must proxify requests from users to Apache or Node depends on host.

But I'm not sure that this is right way.

Comment: I have this article for start http://readystate4.com/2011/07/15/nginx-apache-and-node-all-living-harmony/ but how can I configure hosts for nginx to use http://node.dev.loc for one of my node applications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is very simple: create a separate virtual host is NGINX and map it to Node.js.